# Deserialize returns 0 but should be returning 1?

Tags: deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to Deserialize an XML file using a List of objects. My code executes without exceptions but it always returns `0` for the count (`mRules.Count`)?

mRules is always returning count = 0, I can't figure out why?  I am guessing it's something related to List of Objects (List(Of Rule)) in my Rules class ... or perhaps something more simple on the usage of "name" as an attribute rather than element?

```
 <Rules>
    <Rule name="TV Offset">
        <ProductList>
            <Product name="Sony" spawnRatio="1">
                <Color r=".7" g=".8" b=".7"/>
            </Product>
            <Product name="LG" spawnRatio="1">
                <Color r=".7" g=".8" b=".7"/>
            </Product>
        </ProductList>
        <RegionList>
            <Location name="California South"/>
            <Location name="Texas East"/>
            <Location name="California North"/>
            <Location name="Nevada"/>
        </RegionList>
    </Rule>
    <Rule name="Oven Offset">
        <ProductList>
            <Product name="GE" spawnRatio="1">
                <Color r=".2" g=".2" b=".1"/>
            </Product>
            <Product name="KitchenAid" spawnRatio="2">
                <Color r=".2" g=".2" b=".1"/>
            </Product>
        </ProductList>
        <RegionList>
            <Location name="California South"/>
            <Location name="Texas East"/>
            <Location name="Washington North"/>
            <Location name="Oregon"/>
        </RegionList>
    </Rule> 
</Rules>
    
    
    Imports System.Xml.Serialization
    
    <Serializable(), XmlRoot("Rules"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(Rules))>
    Public Class Rules
    
        <XmlElement("Rule")>
        Private _rule As List(Of Rule)
        Public Property Rule() As List(Of Rule)
            Get
                Return _rule
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of Rule))
                _rule = value
            End Set
        End Property
    
    End Class

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable(), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(Rule))>
Public Class Rule

    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' TODO: ProductList  

    ' TODO: RegionList 

End Class


            Public Sub Load(ByVal vFile As String)
    
                Dim reader As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Rules))
                Dim ruleFile As New StreamReader(vFile)
    
                Dim mRules As Rules
                mRules = CType(reader.Deserialize(ruleFile), Rules)
    
            End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

<XmlElement("Rule")>

Was on the wrong line, it needs to be above the Public Property Rule()... same for the XmlAttribute.

WRONG:

```
<XmlElement("Rule")>
Private _rule As List(Of Rule)
Public Property Rule() As List(Of Rule)
    Get
        Return _rule
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Rule))
        _rule = value
    End Set
End Property
```

CORRECT:

```
    Private _rule As List(Of Rule)
    <XmlElement("Rule")>
    Public Property Rule() As List(Of Rule)
        Get
            Return _rule
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Rule))
            _rule = value
        End Set
    End Property
```